# visual c++ LNK1120 LNK2019 error

Tags: visual-c++

I'm a newbie, maybe it's a trivial question.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

istream& func(istream&);

int main()
{
    func(cin);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

istream& fumc(istream& is) {
    int num;
    while (is >> num, !is.eof()) {
        cout << num<<endl;
    }
    is.clear();
    return is;
}
```

I got some errors LNK1120 and LNK2019.
Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: `func` != `fumc`

Comment: Thank you, I just notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function declaration and definition has mismatch name 
define it as 
istream& func(istream& is)
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a `linker error`. Add any additional dependencies in Configuration **Properties->Linker**.

Hope it helps.